# Install ecpg on Centos 8

Tags: centos, yum, postgresql

How can I install the `ecpg` tool in Centos8?

According to its description, it is included in the `postgresql-server-devel.x86_64package`, but once installed I can't found it. Moreover, it seems it is not included in the `rpm -ql` output.

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

The binary is included in `postgresql#-devel` where # is the version number.

For example, if it's Postgresql 12, the package that contains it is `postgresql12-devel`.

You can see this with:

```
yum provides */ecpg
```

That will show the packages that contain it.